# How $\log(t)$ can be the limit of $t^r$, where $r\to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My class is solving the [Cauchy-Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) differential equation $a t^2 y'' + b t y' + c y = 0$.  The solutions are powers of $t$, $y = t^r$ and then you solve for $r$ using the characteristic equation $a r^2 + (b-a) r + c = 0$.  This has two roots $r = \overline{r} \pm \Delta r$ and the general solution is $y = A t^{\overline{r} + \Delta r} + B t^{\overline{r} - \Delta r }$.

What happens if we get double roots, i.e. $(b-a)^2 = 4ac$ or $\Delta r = 0$? We guess a solution of $y = t^r \ln t$.  Can derive this guess taking the limit of two distinct roots solution as $\Delta r$ tends to 0?  In some sense 
$$ A t^{\overline{r} + \Delta r} + B t^{\overline{r} - \Delta r }
= t^{\overline{r}} (  A t^{ \Delta r} + B t^{ - \Delta r }) \to  t^{\overline{r}} (C + D \ln t )$$
for some constants $A,B,C,D$.

In a way, it is plausible the limit works this way because of the integral formula:
$$ \int t^{r - 1}\mathrm dt = \begin{cases}  \frac{t^r}{r} & r \neq 0\\ \ln t  & r = 0 \end{cases}$$
And I expect this is coming into play in the Euler-Cauchy equation.  How to make it rigorous, though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything works out as long as you are careful about the additive constants in your integrals!  What you should actually have written is

$$\int_1^{x} t^{r-1} \, dt = \begin{cases} \frac{x^r - 1}{r} & r \neq 0 \\\ \ln x & r = 0 \end{cases}$$

and then I leave it as an exercise to verify that indeed $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{x^r - 1}{r} = \ln x$ for positive $x$ (note that this already follows from the above integral formula since integrals respect uniform limits).  A great example of the importance of keeping track of that $+C$.  This exact limit came up in another math.SE question which I can't track down.

In the application to the Euler-Lagrange equation I guess you can take $A = -B = \frac{1}{\Delta r}$; then the limit becomes $2 \ln t$.  Probably you can get this by using the right initial conditions.

Comment: It was http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/how-do-i-evaluate-this-integral/.

Comment: sweet! I don't think I've seen that limit before.

Comment: @john: it is a straightforward application of l'Hopital's after dividing by ln x.  Alternately you can write x^r = e^{r ln x} = 1 + r ln x + ...